# Connect exist Browser with Pupperteer use mac

Tags: node.js, macos, web

What I do:

1. open 9222 port in chorme by:

```
open -a "Google Chrome" --args --remote-debugging-port=9222
```

2. run my code :

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer-core');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.connect({browserWSEndpoint:'ws://127.0.0.1:9222/'})
  .catch(error => {
    console.error('Error occured:', error)
  });
  
  const page = await browser.newPage();
// ...
  await browser.close();
})();
```

it expect to connect to my chorme which is already open, however it give the unconnect alert like :

```
Error occured: ErrorEvent {
  [Symbol(kTarget)]: WebSocket {
    _events: [Object: null prototype] { open: [Function], error: [Function] },
    _eventsCount: 2,
    _maxListeners: undefined,
    _binaryType: 'nodebuffer',
    _closeCode: 1006,
    _closeFrameReceived: false,
    _closeFrameSent: false,
    _closeMessage: <Buffer >,
    _closeTimer: null,
    _extensions: {},
    _paused: false,
    _protocol: '',
    _readyState: 3,
    _receiver: null,
    _sender: null,
    _socket: null,
    _bufferedAmount: 0,
    _isServer: false,
    _redirects: 0,
    _url: 'ws://127.0.0.1:9222/',
    _originalIpc: false,
    _originalSecure: false,
    _originalHostOrSocketPath: '127.0.0.1:9222',
    _req: null,
    [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
  },
  [Symbol(kType)]: 'error',
  [Symbol(kError)]: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:9222
      at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1595:16) {
    errno: -61,
    code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
    syscall: 'connect',
    address: '127.0.0.1',
    port: 9222
  },
  [Symbol(kMessage)]: 'connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:9222'
}
/Users/huangjingwen/workspace/Meru/example.js:24
  const page = await browser.newPage();
                             ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'newPage')
    at /Users/huangjingwen/workspace/Meru/example.js:24:30
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)

Node.js v20.7.0
```

I also tried to turn off my firewall, and unable proxy setting.
But neither worked.
I use

```
node -> stable (-> v20.7.0) 
puppeteer@21.3.4
chorme 116.0.5845.187
```

I search a lot of answer from internet, but cannot find a solution.

Comment: I tried same thing in windows, and it works. I believe the problem is on mac firewall or something, but have no idea how to solve it